What is the best practice regarding the version number within the SPFx package-solution.json?
After the SPFx package which version number has been updated is uploaded, the update is sometimes displayed within the site without clicking the get prior version button?
If there are many sites with the same SPFx app installed, how can I give updates to the app within each site after that app has been updated with a new version (it's impractical to do this manually for each site), PowerShell script might be an option, but it doesn't seem to be a sensible one either!
So what is the best practice?
Thank you!

You can set skipFeatureDeployment property. Follow: Tenant-wide Deployment of SharePoint Framework Extensions.

No,I can not do it this way.Not all site need this SPFx extension.
